# Why can't I define this symbol in masm?

Tags: assemblies, symbols, masm

I'm just starting to learn intel assembly and I'm having trouble with this simple program.

```
main    PROC            ;program execution begins here
A   =   1               ;define A with 1
B   =   12o             ;define B with 12 octal
X   dword   A1h         ;initialize the variable X with value A1 hex
Y   dword   11001001b   ;initialize the variable Y with value 11001001 binary

SUM dword   0       ;initializes the sum variable to 0
ADD EAX, A          ;adds A to sum
ADD EAX, B          ;adds B to sum
ADD EAX, X          ;adds X to sum
ADD EAX, Y          ;adds Y to sum
MOV SUM, EAX        ;
exit                ;end of program
main    ENDP
```

but whenever I try to build this it says "Error A2006: undefined symbol : A1"
if anyone could help me that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write 0A1h because A1h looks like a variable name.

Comment: Thanks that did it, sorry if that was such an easy question this is my first time using assembly.

Comment: @RyanStull You may want to [read the MASM manual](http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf) if you intend on working in assembly. Page 16 on integer constants: "Hexadecimal numbers must always start with a decimal digit (0–9). If necessary, add a leading zero to distinguish between symbols and hexadecimal numbers that start with a letter. For example, MASM interprets ABCh as an identifier."

Answer (score 2):

This says to prepend hex values starting with letters with a 0 http://www.piclist.com/techref/language/masms.htm